# Sylius / Symfony standard version control flow using Git

Tags: git, symfony, sylius

Could anyone provide the correct version control flow of Sylius / Symfony?
(I am now to Symfony / Sylius.)

I have setup a UAT server for Sylius and would like to have development server on my own environment. Should I create a git repo from UAT and then install sylius on my environment and pull from git?

What are the files should be included in git? Sylius already included gitignore file but seems some of them should ignore (e.g.: /web/)
Should I just git /app/ ?

Comment: This seems like a very broad question.  Can you narrow this down to just one question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at Composer first. Unless the previous maintainers did something weird, all dependencies (amongst which Sylius and Symfony) are defined and required via Composer and installed via `composer install` in the `vendor` folder.

Except the `vendor` folder, everything else should be versioned. Only, don't store passwords in Git; use a git-ignored `parameters.yml` or even better environment variables. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html for a full explanation.